# Как подружить Docker и apache?

Tags: php, apache, docker

Всем привет, пытаюсь разобраться в PHP, apache и сопутствующем. Смотрю уроки. Там лектор ставит apache на одной виртуальной машине, nginx на другой и сам работает в основной. На сколько я понял, не получится развернуть два сервера просто на линухе. Дак вот я поставил Docker, вроде даже поставил образы php, apache, nginx, mysql (но не покидает ощущение, что криво поставил). Дальше в уроках настройку этих серверов проводит в ручную, в файлах которые лежат по пути etc/apache2/... Дак вот вопрос: что делать, когда развернул всё это добро через docker? Есть те, кто знает и может подсказать? Я в диком ступоре и не понимаю, то ли сносить всё нафиг и ставить виртуалки и ковыряться так... то ли что вообще делать. Ни в Dockere ни в PHP не разбираюсь, только начинаю изучать.

Answer (score 0):

вопрос слишком глобален. лучше «есть слона по кусочкам».

начните, например, с банального — запустить программу *apache* внутри контейнера.

1. при запуске контейнера надо (в данном случае) в первую очередь позаботиться о том, чтобы можно было добраться до *tcp*-порта. программа *apache* по умолчанию слушает порт 80, свяжем его с портом (к примеру) 4444 в хост-ситеме:

   ```
   $ docker run -it --rm -p 4444:80 debian bash
   ```
2. внутри контейнера обновим список пакетов:

   ```
   # apt update
   ```
3. установим пакет `apache2`:

   ```
   # apt install -y apache2
   ```
4. и запустим программу *apache* (запуск демонов, осуществляемый из пост-инсталляционных скриптов пакетов, внутри контейнеров обычно блокируется):

   ```
   # /etc/init.d/apache2 start
   ```

проверим в браузере в хост-системе, обратившись по адресу `http://localhost:4444`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

пояснения к опциям программы *docker*:

- `-it` — собственно, это две опции `-i -t`, нужны для нормальной работы интерактивных программ, запущенных внутри контейнера
- `--rm` — автоматически удалить контейнер после завершения его работы
- `-p 4444:80` — связать порт хост-системы 4444 с портом 80 внутри контейнера
- `debian` — имя образа, из которого будет создан контейнер
- `bash` — команда, которую надо выполнить внутри контейнера