# Не запускается docker container с ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, docker, docker-compose

Пытаюсь запустить Ubuntu в докер контейнере. Использую `Dockerfile` с содержимым:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
```

Или `docker-compose.yml` с содержимым:

```
version: '3'

services:
  ubuntu:
    image: ubuntu:18.04
    ports:
      - 32769:80
    volumes:
      - /var/www:/var/www
```

Делаю по минимуму, хочу запустить и посмотреть, что всё работает. Попытаться зайти в сам контейнер.

Но проблема в том, что контейнер не запускается и лежит в списке остановленных

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES


$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS                   NAMES
ea3715e0c4f7        docker-compose-ubuntu-latest_ubuntu   "/bin/sh -c /bin/bash"   4 minutes ago       Exited (0) 4 minutes ago                           docker-compose-ubuntu-latest_ubuntu_1
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём может быть проблема?
Только начинаю изучать докер, возможно делаю что-то не так.

Спасибо.

**P.S.**
Пробовал изменять `Dockerfile` следующим образом:

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install apache2 -y
RUN service apache2 start
CMD /bin/bash
```

но контейнер всё равно не стартует.
Даже не могу понять в чём может быть проблема. Никаких ошибок нет, просто не запускается.

Через docker-compose получается запустить связку нескольких уже готовых образов, но запустить что-то адекватное самому не получается.

Comment: если [протекают дырявые абстракции](http://local.joelonsoftware.com/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%94%D1%8B%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%90%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9) (в виде докерфайлов-компоузов и т.п. надстроек), попробуйте [без них](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/908096/178576).

Comment: @alexander-barakin
Спасибо, помог запуск с `-it`

Посмотрю подробнее об этих ключах и буду экспериментировать дальше

Comment: docker-compose не дырявая абстракция, а очень умная и удобная обёртка для управления приложением. Если читать и использовать примеры из официальной документации всё будет работать и станет очень даже понятным через некоторое время. **Опции в Docker - это ключевая составляющая**. Изучите их. Начните с Docker, потом Docker Compose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рекомендую посмотреть вот [этот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44376852/how-to-start-apache2-automatically-in-a-ubuntu-docker-container) вопрос в stackoverflow.

Если кратко, то в первом случае (до P.S) apache не запускается по двум причинам: (1) по-умолчанию он отсутствует в образе ubuntu (2) отсутствует команда запуска apache. Во втором случае (после P.S) проблема отсутствия apache устранена и осталось лишь прописать в CMD вашего докерфайла верную команду, например:

```
CMD apachectl -D FOREGROUND
```

А теперь полный ответ.

Для того чтобы нам запустить апач в докере необходимо создать файл Dockerfile следующего содержания (скопировано из обозначенной мной ссылки):

```
FROM ubuntu

# File Author / Maintainer
MAINTAINER rmuktader

# Update the repository sources list
RUN apt-get update

# Install and run apache
RUN apt-get install -y apache2 && apt-get clean

#ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/sbin/apache2", "-k", "start"]


#ENV APACHE_RUN_USER www-data
#ENV APACHE_RUN_GROUP www-data
#ENV APACHE_LOG_DIR /var/log/apache2

EXPOSE 80
CMD apachectl -D FOREGROUND
```

Далее из директории, в которой лежит Dockerfile, запускаем сборку образа

```
docker build -t apache .
```

В результате будет создан образ `apache:latest`, из которого можно запустить контейнер командой

```
docker run -it -p 8080:80 apache
```

И если всё хорошо, то можно переходить в браузере по адресу `localhost:8080` и наблюдать стартовую страницу апача.

Для композа файл `docker-compose.yml` будет выглядеть приблизительно так:

```
version: '3'

services:
  apache:
    image: apache:latest
    ports:
      - 32769:80
    volumes:
      - /var/www:/var/www
```

Естественно, необходимо убедиться, что в директории `/var/www` Вашей хост-машины существует нечто "читабельное" для апача.

Запускаем:

```
docker-compose up
```

В браузере переходим в адресу `localhost:32769` и наблюдаем содержимое директории `/var/www` хост-машины

Answer (score 0):

Сам столкнулся с данной ситуации, но ответ неправильный.
Человеку нужно запустить только чистую убудут. Проблема в том, что без дополнительных ключей она сразу завершится так как контейнер будет изолированный и собственно управлять ОС не получится, поэтому при запуске нужно использовать ключи -it. То есть команда будет выглядеть так:

```
sudo docker run -it ubuntu
```